# How do I scroll up using a keyboard using the terminator terminal emulator?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-11.10, terminator

I use Ubuntu 11.10 and recently switched to `terminator` for my terminal. I'm happy with it with one exception, I cannot figure out how to scroll up using the keyboard. I used to use `gnome-terminal` and would <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+{<kbd>↑</kbd> || <kbd>PgUp</kbd>} but cannot find a keybinding for scrolling in `terminator`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> works for me. Failing that, right click > Preferences > Keybindings will allow you to set it to whatever you want.

Comment: If you want to be able to scroll line by line as I did, you can use CTRL + SHIFT + Up/Down keys.

Answer (score 17):

You cannot set a keybinding for scrolling in the Keybindings preferences of terminator – at least not in the version that comes with Ubuntu 12.10.

That said, scrolling linewise works for me by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>keypad up/down</kbd> (with NumLock activated).

Comment: Why only keypad up/down s? Default up/down keys work for me.

Comment: My `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Up/Down Arrow` is bind to resizing terminator tabs. So instead of arrows, I used `8` and `2` in my numpad (having arrow sign on them) and they work for scrolling! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem with that keybinding is that it isn't actually part of the terminator part of the code, it's part of the terminal (which is vte, or something underneath). Any keybindings that are for the underlying single terminal are not configurable in terminator (which just does the multi-terminal parts, and adds slick plugin features, etc).

I did find that if you use the default setup, the single line scroll only works for the numpad up/down. The reason is that Up is tied to resize_up (similarly for down). If you remap those keys, then you can use the regular arrows to scroll by one line.

It would be nice to find a solution for changing the keybinding in the underlying terminal, but in the meantime, if you want the regular arrows to work, just remap the resize_up and resize_down keybindings.

tested in 0.97 ubuntu 14.04.