# How can I configure Linux Terminator to scroll back one page when I click on the scrollbar?

Tags: linux, scrolling, terminator

I'm using Terminator and I get it that [I can use the keyboard to scroll](https://superuser.com/questions/348385/how-do-i-scroll-up-using-a-keyboard-using-the-terminator-terminal-emulator/348386#348386) or the mouse wheel. What I really want to do to click on the scrollbar anywhere above where the current scroll position is and go back exactly 1 (one) screen (like in Chrome, Firefox, etc). Currently it skips to the place in the buffer where I've clicked (possibly thousands of lines back).

I've looked through all of the Terminator options and I can't find anything. Halp!

(If it matters, I'm using MATE on an AWS Linux 2 Workspaces machine as my desktop).

Answer (score 0):

This two answers may provide some insight if you are using GTK as the window manager. You didn't specify you Linux flavor.

[Unix & Linux board](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276005/scrollbar-moves-to-where-i-click)

[GTK fix Ubuntu board](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295988/how-to-fix-gtk3-scrollbar-behavior)

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question to include that I'm using MATE.